# How do I drop multiple rows based on values in a pandas data frame with 1 line of code?

Tags: python, pandas

I'll post a a little bit of my code here. Basically I've been manually removing 1 row at a time that I don't want, but I want it to look nicer than that, so I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way that at allows me to delete everything in 1 line.

```
data = data[data.city_or_county != 'Alma']
data = data[data.city_or_county != 'Alpine']
data = data[data.city_or_county != 'Altadena']
data = data[data.city_or_county != 'Alsip']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use .isin

```
data[~data.city_or_county.isin(["Alma", "Alpine",
                                                        "Alsip","Altadena"])]
```